# Как в настройках uncrustify задать перевод строки для оператора после if без фигурных скобок?

Tags: c++, c, ide, форматирование

Как в конфигурационном файле для утилиты *uncrustify* задать перевод строки для одиночного оператора после оператора `if` или `for` без фигурных скобок?

```
if(b) i++;   =>   if(b)\n i++;                            
for (i=0;i<5;i++) foo(i);   =>   for (i=0;i<5;i++)\n foo(i);
```

Я нашла настройку для противоположного действия:

```
# Change simple unbraced if statements into a one-liner         
# 'if(b)\n i++;' => 'if(b) i++;'                                  
nl_create_if_one_liner = false         # false/true
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашла ответ:

```
# Whether to put a newline after a virtual brace open with a non-empty body.
# These occur in un-braced if/while/do/for statement bodies.
nl_after_vbrace_open = true    # false/true
```